# how to write a .sh file to make my Linux system run python file directly using ./hello

Tags: python, linux, bash, python-3.x, sh

Suppose I have a hellp.py python file. I found that I only can type command: python hello.py to run my command line, but how can I just type ./hello so that my system can run my hellp.py file?

Comment: Don't use a `.py` extension on your entry point -- it's an *executable*, not a library/module. If you're using setuptools (setup.py), you can have *it* do the work of generating an entry point that invokes a function of your choice in a module of your choice if you really do want your Python scripts to all be libraries by nature -- but it's unlikely that that's something you really need or want to do (and the setuptools-generated entrypoint is still itself a Python script, not a shell script; there's no need for a shell script anywhere).

Comment: BTW, I'd argue that this is very much an XY problem ("I want to do X, but I'm asking how to do Y") -- what you *want* is just to run your Python program by running `./hello`; if a shell script is the right and appropriate way to do that, then let the person answering the question point that out; there's no need to incorporate such an assumption into the question itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run your Python script as an executable, put the right shebang at the top of your .py file. For example, hello.py might be defined as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print('hello, world!')
```

Then you'll need to ensure the execute permission is set on the file:

```
$ chmod u+x hello.py
```

When you run `./hello.py`, the interpreter currently on PATH (including one in a virtualenv if one is activated) will run the Python script.

There are other ways to do this as well with tools like PyInstaller, Py2App, Py2Exe, but I think this is what you're looking for.

EDIT: I noticed that the question specified wanting to just type `./hello` at the command line. There are a couple of ways to tackle this. The first would be to simply knock off the file extension and have the Python file simply named `hello`. The second (and the way I'd recommend) would be to create a link to the file. I'd recommend creating a symlink:

```
$ ln -s hello.py hello
```

This way, the code is still obviously a Python file, but you can access it conveniently.

Comment: Re: setting up entry points without a `.py` extension, arguably the best practice (certainly, the thing that will work across platforms Python supports, including Windows) is using the setuptools entrypoint mechanism: http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html -- after a program so packaged has been installed, scripts that call your desired functions from your chosen modules will be placed in the user's PATH.

Comment: Yeah, `setuptools` is great. I think for someone just getting started with the language or writing a small script (as I suspect the asker is doing), the overhead of using a `setup.py` and then installing it into a virtualenv or even the system site-packages may be a bit overkill.

Setuptools is a great option, and is definitely recommended for anything that needs to be maintained or published to production.